# TFS Burndown chart doesn't appear to be correct - potential bug

Tags: tfs, tfs-workitem, burndowncharts

**PLEASE SEE THE EDIT BELOW, THE REPORT SEEMS TO USE CACHED DATA?**

I cant figure out why there are 89 hours of work remaining, when I have 3 Active Work Items totaling 44 hours:

**My Burndown Chart:**
[image: Burndown Chart]

**Remaining hours on 3 blocked tasks equals 44 hours:**
[image: Remaining hours on 3 blocked tasks equals 44 hours]

**I do set the completed hours when I close my tasks:**
[image: I do set the completed hours when I close my tasks]

> What am I doing wrong with the remaining vs completed hours? is this a bug in TFS?

This seems to be different to previous experiences, I've just started a new job.

**EDIT:**

> Today the report is correct, how do I stop the caching happening?

[image]

Comment: Please explain why you voted to close? Ok I see, off topic. It is debatable since I did use the burndowncharts and work-item-tracking tags.

Comment: Same type of question but no answers: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5984446/update-ssrs-parameter-cache-for-tfs-reports-viewed-in-visual-studio Since the cache was cleared last night I cant confirm that this will be the solution: http://www.ewaldhofman.nl/post/2009/07/06/Clear-the-cache-of-TFS.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This burndown report reads from the cube and not from the operational datastore. The cube is processed every 2 hours.

Comment: +1 Thank you very much Ewald, you'd be a god if you wrote a TFS WorkFlow (ie Process Template) mapping tool to get CMMI, MSF Agile "to be easily upgradable" for vNext. I've got heaps of idea's on this, my profile has my email.